# Connecting LogicApp to D365 CRM using predefined connectors

Tags: azure, dynamics-crm, azure-logic-apps

I'm trying to connect to a D365 CRM instance hosted in Azure using a logic app.

For the connection I use the D365 connector supplying the unique organization name from the CRM with the suffix ".crm4" which I derived from the url of the CRM. I use a service user which has admin privileges and I can login to the instance via a browser. The CRM is hosted under a different tenant, service user and logic app is hosted in my tenant.

Using the get record connector I get the following 404 Error: `CRM organization with unique name 'MyOrgName' not found.`

I am not getting the list of possible CRM names when I try to enter the Organization Name and as a result I have to enter a custom value. Due to that I get no auto complete for the Entity Name as well.

What is missing here? Do I have to expose the CRM in some way? 
Is the service user potentially missing privileges?

Comment: Did you get a chance to check my answer?

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the connection to use your service account credentials, then you will be able to see the CRM in Organization Name field, then Entity Name will be listed.

[image]